# Express session id not saving in cookie (graphql)

Tags: express, session, graphql, session-cookies

I cannot for the life of this program figure out why this cookie isn't being saved in the browser. If I run the graphql playground (which is on port 4000, the same as the server), the session ID will be stored in the browser no problem. I have cors enabled so this shouldn't be blocking this. But if I send the login request from any other url, it won't save it in the browser. I have tried multiple browsers and it won't save on any of them and I've tried logging the sessions to make sure I am actually saving them. Any ideas?

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga');
const session = require('express-session');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const ms = require('ms');


const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    isLoggedIn: Boolean!
  }
  type Mutation {
    logIn(email: String!, password: String!): Boolean!
    signUp(email: String!, password: String!): Boolean!
  }
`

// mock mockDBbase
const mockDB = {};

const resolvers = {

  Query: {
    // is the user authenticated
    isLoggedIn: (parent, args, ctx) => {
      return ctx.session.isLoggedIn === true;
    }
  },

  Mutation: {

    // user can sign up for a new account
    signUp: async (parent, { email, password }, ctx) => {
      // if user is already in the DB
      if (mockDB[email]) {
        throw new Error('This user already exists, please log in.');
      }
      const saltRounds = 14; // roughly 1.5 secs on 2GHZ CPU
      // store password in mock DB (replace with real DB)
      mockDB[email] = {
        // salt and hash pw
        password: await bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds),
      };
      return true;
    },

    // authenticates user into respective account
    logIn: async (parent, { email, password }, ctx) => {
      // grab user from DB
      const user = mockDB[email];
      if (user) {
        // make sure pw matches
        if (await bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
          // set user logged in flag
          ctx.session.isLoggedIn = true;
          return true;
        }
        throw new Error('User email or password is incorrect.');
      }
      throw new Error('User email or password is incorrect.');
    }
  }
}

// opts
const opts = {
  port: 4000,
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: "*"
  }
};

// context
const context = req => ({
  session: req.request.session,
});

// server
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context,
});

const SESSION_SECRET = 'my-super-secret-secret';

server.express.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy

// session middleware 
server.express.use(
  session({
    name: 'SSID',
    // change this to randomly generate a secret
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      maxAge: ms('1d'),
    }
  })
);

// start server
server.start(opts, () => console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${opts.port}`));
```

Comment: So when you are logging in do you mean logging in through graphql mutation or logging into through session login in express?  Either way, could you post your network request for that and the response?   I have a hunch what the issue is.

Comment: So I actually just found out what the issue was. Graphql playground has an issue still open for it. Even if you set credentials to be sent with your query it will not send them along with your request. It will still hit the api fine, but the cookie will not be set. 

https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground/issues/748